Mutt: how to disable specifying the filename for a single inline plain text attachment?
I noticed that in the Compose menu, Mutt shows a dash before the content disposition symbol (I as in inline) of the actual message:

Regular attachments do not have this dash present.
By trial and error, I have determined that for such an attachment with a dash, no filename is given in the message source; i.e., if inline (- I  ...), the attachment is not listed among attachments by the recipient's mail user agent (MUA).
If one were to:

add a different plain text attachment (<attach-file>),
change its disposition to inline (<toggle-disposition>),
remove the original message (i.e., the original plain text attachment; <detach-file>), and
send the message (send-message>),

the recipient would see the replacement text as intended, but they would also see the single plain text attachment among the message attachments.
Renaming the attachment (<rename-attachment>) is of no use, because Mutt will not permit a blank name (if, indeed, a blank name were to solve the issue).
How does one tell Mutt to handle this new -- replacement -- attachment as the message text, i.e., make Mutt omit the respective filename in the outgoing message source and display the dash before the content disposition symbol?
Edit: Please note that I would like to implement all this in a Mutt macro.
Thanks.

You can always postpone the message and remove the ; filename=file by hand in the postponed file and resume the sending in mutt afterwards.

Thanks; I admit that that would be a way to do it. However, I'd like to implement all this in a macro (i.e., doing anything manually is not an option). Sorry, I should have specified it right away.
